# Is there any cause for flutter app not able to connect to VM observatory service?

Tags: flutter

I want to send data from my flutter app to Mysql in phpMyAdmin,but i get the message
Incompatible protocol version: client=3.26 vm=4.4
Failed to connect to the VM observatory service at: ws://127.0.0.1:64371/OyIC0eA1EIo=/ws
java.io.IOException: Incompatible protocol version: client=3.26 vm=4.4

and i would like to ask  about the possible cause of this problem and solutions

I tried other solutions like flutter clean and rebuild and also changing the api version but still counted to nothing